# React: How to avoid clicking under an element that just disappeared?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, touch

I made a React component that works like Mac/Windows top menu bar. Everything works great, except for one thing - on touch screens, when a user selects an option from the menu, the click is being registered underneath, which causes a big problem.

I have prepared a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-brattain-bymwub) with minimal reproducible example to represent the issue. To reproduce the problem, please follow these steps *on mobile*, because on desktop it works fine:

1. Click on the green *Over* box - it prints to the console that *Under* box has been clicked.
2. To repeat, click *Show Over* button.

The problem seems to be that clicking on mobile is delayed and it doesn't care what triggered it. I'm hiding the *Over* box `onPointerUp` and the click happens anyway on whatever was under it. `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't work, because the tree hierarchy doesn't apply here.

Here's the component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const callback = () => setIsVisible(false);

            window.addEventListener("pointerdown", callback);

            return () => window.removeEventListener("pointerdown", callback);
        },
        []
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                    setIsVisible(true);
                }}
                onPointerDown={event => event.stopPropagation()}
            >
                Show Over
            </button>
            <div>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => console.log("Clicked under :(")}
                >
                    Under
                </button>
                {isVisible && (
                    <div>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onPointerDown={event => event.stopPropagation()}
                            onPointerUp={() => {
                                setIsVisible(false);
                            }}
                        >
                            Over
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The problem can be reproduced in Chrome dev tools with emulated touch, as well as on Safari iOS (but not always) and in Samsung mobile browser. Haven't checked in other browsers.

EDIT

I found an imperfect solution, which I'd like to improve. I captured an `onClick` event and removed the listener after 200ms:

```
onPointerUp={() => {
    setIsVisible(false);

    const lockClick = event => event.stopPropagation();

    window.addEventListener("click", lockClick, true);

    window.setTimeout(
        () => window.removeEventListener("click", lockClick, true),
        200
    );
}}
```

Before, I delayed the `setIsVisible(false)` itself and that worked too, as the *Over* box would still be mounted when the click happens. But the downside was that there was a visual delay before the box would disappear.

I'm still looking for the better solution, one without `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it can be fixed by wrapping setIsVisble with a setTimeout function as shown below:

```
<button
    type="button"
    className="button button-over"
    onPointerDown={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
    onPointerUp={() => {
        setTimeout(() => setIsVisible(false), 5)
    }}
>
```

I tried it on Android's Chrome and on Safari.

Comment: This is actually how I did it temporarily, but it feels sketchy. I experimented with the timeouts and `50` seems to be working fine, while smaller amount doesn't work. Pretty sure in some cases (slowdowns) `50` wouldn't be enough neither, so I'm looking for something more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You are stopping the propagation of the `pointerDown` event, but not the propagation of the onClick event, which is what the "under" div is listening for.  There are lots of ways to fix this, but the easiest is to change your "under" div to

```
<button
    type="button"
    onPointerDown={() => console.log("Clicked under :(")}>
    Under
</button>
```

I'm not totally sure why it's an issue only in mobile - maybe someone else can chime in here, but I suspect that the browser probably treats pointer events differently in desktop mode and maybe bundles them with mouse events or something.

Comment: I'll also add that it's a little strange to be attaching the `pointerDown` handler to the `window` object, and ALSO to the "over" element directly, especially since they do the same thing.  One or the other is probably unnecessary.

Comment: There are two listeners, because `window`'s one is supposed to hide the element when the pointer is down anywhere in the window, but element's `onPointerDown` prevents it from being hidden when pointer is down on the element. I hope I explained that clearly.